# Update View After Selecting Date Range (Rails, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a table that shows sales by event for a bunch of different date ranges (last month, last week, etc.)

```
    <% @events.each do |event| %> 
      <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even") -%>">
       <td class=" "><%= number_to_currency(stripe_to_display(event.sales(VARIABLE_1,VARIABLE_2))) %></td>
       <td class=" "><%= number_to_currency(stripe_to_display(event.sales(0,0))) %></td>
       <td class=" "><%= number_to_currency(stripe_to_display(event.sales(7,0))) %></td>
       <td class=" "><%= number_to_currency(stripe_to_display(event.sales(30,0))) %></td>
       <td class=" "><%= number_to_currency(stripe_to_display(event.sales)) %></td>
      </tr>
     <% end %>
```

That first td row calculates sales based on a CUSTOM date range. An event instance can calculate sales based on two integers (`start_day` and `end_day`). (They represent the number of days from today.)

And when a date range is selected, this Javascript is called:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#sales_date_range').daterangepicker(
{ 
format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
startDate: $.now,
endDate: $.now
},
function(start, end, label) {
var now = new Date();
var start_days_ago = (now - start) / 86400000;
var end_days_ago = (now - end) / 86400000;
start_days_ago = start_days_ago.toFixed();
end_days_ago = end_days_ago.toFixed();
}
);

});
```

Importantly, that last Javascript function calculates `start_days_ago` and `end_days_ago` which are what an `event` instance needs to calculate sales for a custom date period.

So my problem: I can figure out the required arguments in JS, but don't know how to get them to the ERB file.

I assume it has something to do with AJAX and conceptually this is wrong, but my hours of searching haven't gotten me any closer to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

I created params with the JS days variables:

```
var path = '?start_day=' + start_days_ago + '&end_day=' + end_days_ago
```

and then refreshed the page with the new path:

```
window.location = path;
```

Then my controller has access to the two arguments:

```
@start_day = params[:start_day].to_i
@end_day = params[:end_day].to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a more snappy update (not refreshing the whole page), you could also load part of the page in. Keep the changes you made (Using `params[:start_day]` etc.), but change your javascript to something like:

```
$("#events").load('path/to/action #events', {start_day: start_days_ago, end_day: end_days_ago});
```

And give your table the id of `events`. Then only the table it self will update, ajax style. Note that you might have to deal with error handling and that the page url won't update this way.